# SQL update, set, case: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-update

Table:`Person`

```
+------+-------+
| name |  age  |
+------+-------+
| abc  |  NULL |
+------+-------+
```

I want to update `age` in two conditions

1. If age in the table is `NULL`, set it to the var `$year`
2. If age in the table is **NOT** `NULL`, **increase** it by `$year`

I have the following code. But it does not update my age in table. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Person`
        SET age =
            CASE
                WHEN age == null THEN $year
                ELSE age + $year
            END
        WHERE name='abc'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare a value with `null` directly by doing `age = null`, as `null` has no type and is sort of "undefined". You need to check if the value *is null*, by doing `CASE WHEN age IS NULL`.

You should also be using a prepared statement here, since you're dealing with variables directly in the query.

```php
$name = 'abc';
$sql = "UPDATE `Person`
        SET age =
            CASE
                WHEN age IS NULL THEN ?
                ELSE age + ?
            END
        WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("iis", $year, $year, $name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

You can reduce the number of parameters a bit by first getting the current age, or zero if it was null, then adding the `$year`.

```php
$name = 'abc';
$sql = "UPDATE `Person`
        SET age = (CASE WHEN age IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE age END) + ?
        WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("is", $year, $name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Isn't that 'comparing against NULL' !?!

Comment: Supposed it could be described more explicitly, but the point remains that you can't compare against a null-value through `=`, you need to check if it *is* null.

Comment: @Qirel Understood you perfectly! Thanks a lot!